# FragmentManager - not able to access the fragment in another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have two fragments like left panel one fragment and right side another fragment having.

The left panel fragment i having the add button from there when i click add button it launches another activity, from this activity i am trying the access the fragment but i am not getting.

This is the code i am using in my activity

LeftFragment left = (LeftFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
finish();

Can anyone help me.

Comment: it seems right,but what did u do with "left", you 've just finished your Activity!what do you want to do with your leftfragment?

Comment: yes, I have the Add button in leftfragement and when clicking add button i am launching another activity from there need to get the leftfragment context.

Comment: sorry i can't help you with this information more,the line of getting fragment is right but i don't know how you are trying to use it,pls provide more information and implementation code

Comment: Arash, I am having the ListFragment class that with this i have the button for adding new items. When i clicks the add button just launching the another acitvity which has set of fields from here how can i access the ListFragment

Answer (score 0):

Well, this because you can't get access to `FragmentManager` of other `Activity`, and it`s absolutely normal.

You can simply commit second fragment to the same container as a first one (use single `Activity`) and use method `setCustomAnimations(...)` for your transaction to animation.

Good luck!

Comment: No. My query is leftfragment i am having the add button. when i click the add button it launches another activity not a fragment. from there i need get the leftfragment

Comment: @user1584844 Sorry but it's not possible to do that in this way, each Activity have it's own `FragmentManager`

Answer (score 0):

you can define another ListFragment in your Fragment like this:

```
SecondListFragment SecondListFragment= (SecondListFragment )getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.second_list_fragment);
SecondListFragment.SetupSecondFragmentList();//its written on onListItemClick in FirstFragment
```

SetupSecondFragmentList() is a function that setup a list view in my Second ListFragment which has called from first one

Comment: This is i have done Arash. I am not starting another fragment. From the LeftListfragment i am launching the activity not a fragment.